# How to Paste from UIPasteBoard into WKWebView?

Tags: swift, wkwebview, uipasteboard

I am attempting to have a `UIBarButton` (right side) as a paste button.  The user will have already copied text to the `UIPasteBoard` in the previous `ViewController`.  When hitting the `UIBarButton` (Paste), The text should appear on the text field on the website that the user is focused on.  For example, if the user taps the `Google search box`, then presses Paste, the text should appear.

I have only found solutions to use `UIPasteBoard` with strings to paste into `UITextFields`, `UITextViews` within the app and not into `WKWebViews`.

```
@IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Paste", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(pasteText))

    let myURL = URL(string:"https://www.google.com")
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    webView.load(myRequest)
}

@objc func pasteText() {
    // Code?
}
```

[image: UIPasteBoard Picture Graphic]

Trying to use `UIPasteBoard` to paste text into a textfield in a website (`WKWebView`).

Comment: Use Javascript in webview

Comment: I’m not following... so I should be able to use javascript in the web view to access UI Elements outside of the web view? Any resources you can reference please?